# Did Duncan Jones intentionally use actors of different ethnic groups in Warcraft movie?

Tags: casting, warcraft

In the *Warcraft* movie, there are actors which represent the different races on earth. Such as the elf king (or ambassador), the captain of the guards, etc.

Did the director intentionally choose these actors to send an anti-racism message? Or is this how he makes his movies?

It's a brilliant way to send a message, but I'm not sure if it's a good idea to do this in a movie that happens in another universe, while these ethnicities belong to earth?

Comment: He couldn't find enough green 3-legged actors with just the right shade of scales... so he had to use humans...

Comment: @Tetsujin I'm referring to the african captain and the asian ambassador :)

Comment: All the ethnicities he used belong to earth... that was my point. "White" *is also an ethnicity*.

Comment: The problem you're experiencing is the tone of the last sentence ... which sounds like "its fine if its an anti racism message, but if it wasn't why didn't he just use white actors".  I'm sure that's not what you're intending to convey - but it is worth pointing out that in a fictional other universe, why wouldn't the people be be like the black or asian actors you refer to?

Comment: @iandotkelly They should be the races of their own, such as Garona. Please don't interpret racism here, the question is about appearance of people in different worlds.

Comment: I'm just interpreting the previous comments and suggesting you might consider rewording to avoid misinterpretation.  I'm not familiar with the Warcraft universe, but why couldn't the human's in that universe have racial differences, perhaps the other species like Orcs (or whatever they are called in WC) have racial differences that is hard for human's to identifty.

Comment: Note that skin color is an option in World of Warcraft (the game) for humans. Therefore, the source material already includes different races for Humans (I think that what the game refers to as "races", such as Orcs, Trolls, Humans, Gnomes,  ... should technically be called "species", as they cannot interbreed). The director wasn't adding a message of his own, he was simply basing himself on the source material.

Comment: @Flater I haven't played the game World of Warcraft, but didn't see any color in the WC3. If you're sure, please post this as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I'm not quite sure why this is closed as "unclear what you're asking". The title is a clear question. The grammar in the question body could be improved, but the question itself seems clear enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The director wasn't adding a message of his own, he was simply basing himself on the source material. Not all Warcraft humans are white.

Although the Warcraft lore spans several games, and I'm not sure if every game contains skin color variations; **World of Warcraft** definitely contains skin color options:

[image]

*Keep in mind that some of the games are rather old, and played in a top down view. Skin color would hardly be noticeable on an old monitor with what we now consider horribly low resolution graphics. It's possible that the **lore** included skin color differences, but the earlier **games** did not due to technical limitations.*

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess that was some raged flagging :)